# No manual entry for termios

Tags: 22.04

I installed Ubuntu today to follow along with a tutorial. It requires native API call to *`termios`* library and I intend to call those APIs in my code which is in Java. I want to refer to man page of *termios* in terminal but when I type the command `man termios` I get the output as `no manual entry for termios`. Do i need to separately install `termios` from somewhere and is it not included in ubuntu itself? Please advice how can I install that library if I need to.

Comment: There should be a man page for temios, see: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html  (found via https://www.google.com/search?q=man+termios )

Comment: I know I can look it up on google but I want to understand why it doesn't work on terminal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The termios API is part of the GNU C library, so to use it in your code you will need to install the `libc6-dev` package.

The manual page however is provided by the `manpages-dev` package:

```
$ dpkg -S $(man -w termios)
manpages-dev: /usr/share/man/man3/termios.3.gz
```

Comment: I was searching for that too.... but now I do not have to search anymore   (Because `man termios` simply works for me)

Comment: It worked, thanks so much! :)